# flatbuffers is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, flatbuffers

I'm writing a nodeJs application that uses google flat buffer.

I installed flatc on my macbook pro and compiled the following schema:

namespace MyAlcoholist;

```
table Drink {
 drink_type_name: string;
 drink_company_name: string;
 drink_brand_name: string;
 drink_flavor_type_name : string;
 liquid_color_type_name : string;
 liquid_color_is_transparent : bool;
 alcohol_vol : float;
 calories_for_100g : uint;
 global_image_id: ulong;
 drink_flavor_id: ulong;
}

table Drinks { drinks:[Drink]; }

root_type Drinks;
```

the schema file is called drink.fbs and it generated a javascript file called drink_generated.js

I include this file in my nodejs application and add data to it using the following code..  this is my flatBufferUtil.js utility file.

```
var flatbuffers = require('../js/flatbuffers').flatbuffers;
var builder = new flatbuffers.Builder();

var drinks = require('../fbs/drinks_generated').MyAlcoholist; // Generated by `flatc`.

function drinkArrayToBuffer(drinkArray) {
var drinksVectArray = [];
drinkArray.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
    var drinkObj = element;
    var drinkBrandName = builder.createString(drinkObj.drink_brand_name);
    var drinkCompanyName = builder.createString(drinkObj.drink_company_name);
    var drinkflavorTypeName = builder.createString(drinkObj.drink_flavor_type_name);
    var drinkTypeName = builder.createString(drinkObj.drink_type_name);
    var liquidColorTypeName = builder.createString(drinkObj.liquid_color_type_name);
    drinks.Drink.startDrink(builder);
    drinks.Drink.addAlcoholVol(builder, drinkObj.alcohol_vol);
    drinks.Drink.addCaloriesFor100g(builder,drinkObj.calories_for_100g);
    drinks.Drink.addDrinkBrandName(builder,drinkBrandName);
    drinks.Drink.addDrinkCompanyName(builder,drinkCompanyName);
    drinks.Drink.addDrinkFlavorId(builder,drinkObj.drink_flavor_id);
    drinks.Drink.addDrinkFlavorTypeName(builder, drinkflavorTypeName);
    drinks.Drink.addDrinkTypeName(builder,drinkTypeName);
    drinks.Drink.addGlobalImageId(builder,drinkObj.global_image_id);
    drinks.Drink.addLiquidColorIsTransparent(builder,drinkObj.is_transparent);
    drinks.Drink.addLiquidColorTypeName(builder,liquidColorTypeName);
    var drink = drinks.Drink.endDrink(builder);
    drinksVectArray.push(drink);
})
var drinksVect = drinks.createDrinksVector(builder,drinksVectArray);
builder.finish(drinksVect);
var buf = builder.dataBuffer();
return buf;
}

module.exports.drinkArrayToBuffer=drinkArrayToBuffer;
```

now when I execute this function it fails with the error `flatbuffers is not defined`.

I debugged my code and I saw that it files on the following line of code:

```
    drinks.Drink.addDrinkFlavorId(builder,drinkObj.drink_flavor_id);
```

if i get inside addDrinkFlavorId function i see this code in drinks_generted.js:

```
MyAlcoholist.Drink.addDrinkFlavorId = function(builder, drinkFlavorId) {
   builder.addFieldInt64(9, drinkFlavorId, flatbuffers.Long.ZERO);
};
```

as you can see it uses `flatbuffers.Long.ZERO` but flatbuffers is not defined in that file at all. the compilation did not provide any errors so what do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like it is a bug... The generated file appears to be meant to exist autonomously from the `flatbuffers` require. However for the custom `flatbuffers.Long` class, the default of `flatbuffers.Long.ZERO` bleeds into the generated file.

While this isn't a solution per-say, one workaround is to manually add the flatbuffers require to the generated file; it's ugly, but it might be better than being blocked until a more appropriate answer (or fix) comes around.

```
// In `drinks_generated.js`
var flatbuffers = require('../js/flatbuffers').flatbuffers;
```

Note:

The `drinks.Drink.addDrinkFlavorId()` and `drinks.Drink.addGlobalImageId()` functions expect `flatbuffers.Long` values to be passed into them, because they were specified as `ulong` in the schema (`fbs` file). So you will need to ensure that you are not trying to pass in a simple `number` type.

For example:

```
var my_long = flatbuffers.Long(100, 0); // low = 100, high = 0
drinks.Drink.addDrinkFlavorId(builder, my_long);
```

As a result, another possible workaround is to change the datatype of those fields in the schema to avoid using `ulong` until it becomes more clear what is going on here.

P.S. I am pretty sure `drinks.createDrinksVector` on line 30 of that snippet should be `drinks.Drinks.createDrinksVector`.

Comment: I filed a bug report on your behalf. Hopefully this will get resolved more definitively. https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/issues/3773

Comment: Just to keep you updated, this has been fixed as of: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/commit/31b30335f6336989216bcdb7dd1178cd08021684